# ng-repeat shows terrible performance with large lists

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm experiencing performance issues when using `ng-repeat` for long lists (thousands of records) that need to be shown within a table.

Here is the HTML I'm using:

```
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="One_Header in Data_List.Header track by $index">{{One_Header}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-model="Data_List" ng-repeat="One_Source in Data_List.Body track by $index" style="cursor:pointer">
                <td ng-repeat="One_Data_Field in One_Source track by $index">{{One_Data_Field}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

The received JSON (takes about 1 second to get it from the server) contains the data as follows:

```
"Data":{
         "Header":["Title_1","Title_2","Title_3"],
         "Body":[
                 ["Rec_1_Data_1","Rec_1_Data_2","Rec_1_Data_3"],
                 ["Rec_2_Data_1","Rec_2_Data_2","Rec_2_Data_3"],
                 ["Rec_3_Data_1","Rec_3_Data_2","Rec_3_Data_3"],
                 :
                 ["Rec_n_Data_1","Rec_n_Data_2","Rec_n_Data_3"]
                ]
}
```

I also tried one-directional binding (i.e. `{{::One_Data_Field}}`) without any noticeable improvement.

As stated above, response arrives within a second and then it takes up to 10 seconds for the table to be built.

Comment: Pagination + lazy loading/endless scrolling are your friends here.

Comment: You can try using vs-repeat. https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat

Comment: Thank you guys for your suggestions. Unfortunately, I'm quite limited to the number of libraries I can include in my project (company policy... don't ask...) and hence must somehow tackle this using a different approach. I was more thinking about something like the following: display into the table, say, the first 100 records, render, and then add chunks in the background (which obviously will cause a re-render, so I'm not sure if this is a good idea at all).

Comment: This [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1173869/ng-repeat-performance-degradation-at-case-of-very) can help you.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov, your article looks promising. Will give it a try (in coming days) and let you know if it resolves my problem. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

in order to improve the performance, you can use pagination directives created using angular js.

[Angular-Paging](https://github.com/brantwills/Angular-Paging)

[pagination](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination)

If you are using Angular material design then I would highly recommend using virtual repeat

[virtual repeat](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/virtualRepeat)

Comment: Thank you @sachilaranawaka. Please see my comment following the original question and a couple of comments from other people.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this sample pagination implementation:

```
        var pageSize = 15;
        $scope.paginationLimit = function(pagesShown) {
            return pageSize * pagesShown.count;
        };

        $scope.hasMoreItemsToShow = function(list, pagesShown) {
           return pagesShown.count < (list.length / pageSize);
        };

        $scope.showMoreItems = function(pagesShown) {               
            pagesShown.count = pagesShown.count + 1;
        };



       <tr ng-model="Data_List" ng-repeat="One_Source in Data_List.Body track by $index " style="cursor:pointer">
            <td ng-repeat="One_Data_Field in One_Source track by $index | limitTo: paginationLimit(pagesShown)">{{One_Data_Field}}</td>
        </tr>

        //sample row with show more button
        <tr class="showMore">                
            <td></td>
            <td class="showBtn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-init="pagesShown={'count': 1}" ng-click="showMoreItems(pagesShown)" ng-show="hasMoreItemsToShow(One_Source track, pagesShown)">Show More</button>
            </td>               
            <td></td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit. Please see my comment above (following my question and two comments).